# On the user edit page, how can I show the "Help text" for my fields after the "Label" and before the selection widget?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have a field on the user edit page that looks like this:

Label: What kind of fruits do you like?

- (checkbox) Apples
- (checkbox) Bananas
- (checkbox) Grapes
- (checkbox) Oranges
- (checkbox) Pears

Description: Check all that apply.

The actual list of checkboxes is quite long (20 or so items) and so I would like to put the description after the label and before the checkboxes-- preferably for all fields displayed using the checkbox widget provided by the [select (or other)](http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module.

How can I adjust where the description is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [theme developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) and point to your widget. It will tell you which hooks and templates are rendering it and what functions/templates you can use to override this functionality.

Often I find myself first copying the default code to the custom function/template and then twicking it to my needs.